# Sending literal accent characters (such as umlaut) on a keyboard that uses them as modifiers

Tags: vim

The point is, my keyboard layout includes a key that, when pressed, waits for the next key input, and if that key fits, it will send an accented character instead of 2 characters. Example: "<kbd>¨</kbd> down, <kbd>¨</kbd> up" + "u" sends `u` umlaut, `ü`. Normally I type the <kbd>¨</kbd> character by itself with "<kbd>¨</kbd> down, <kbd>¨</kbd> up" + <kbd>space</kbd>. But Vim doesn't add the accent character until I type a key that's not space, so "<kbd>¨</kbd> down, <kbd>¨</kbd> up" + <kbd>space</kbd> + "u" leaves me up with  `ü`. I haven't found a clean workaround; mapping `¨`  or `¨¨` doesn't trigger until `ttimeoutlen` is finished, so typing <kbd>¨</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> still sends  `ü` since my ttimeoutlen is non-zero.

Comment: Just proposed some minor enhancements in readability. You could probably replace `"¨ down, ¨ up"` by just `¨` to further enhance that, but I didn't want to be too invasive.

Comment: Maybe this question could help you not directly, but maybe in phrasing your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64367418/using-accent-keys-inside-a-hotstring-correctly-to-substitute-%e2%86%91-and-more-aut - is your keyboard suisse?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a special keyboard to type accents. You can set the `keymap` option:

```
:set kmp=accents
```

---

Type `:help mbyte-keymap` to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have been more clear with my question, but I don't know how to word it any better. My point wasn't my inability to type accents, or wanting to switch layouts, really. Rather I'd like to keep the layout and insert for instance umlauts with umlaut+space like in every other application. Vim does nothing on umlaut+space until I type a non-space character.