# Using accent keys inside a hotstring correctly (^| to substitute ↑ and more, Autohotkey, german keyboard)

Tags: windows, automation, keyboard, autohotkey, uikeyboard

Autohotkey seems to get confused by [diacritic keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) and as such by the behavior of accent keys on some layouts. This basically works like the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key of your mobile phone, but is ended/escaped by typing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> whitout producing that   (space). For a more detailed explanation, please consider the footnote or [link above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic).

So I tried to add Unicode-Arrows as hotstrings in Autohotkey using these keys as lines: <kbd>|</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>_</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>
and these as as arrowtips: <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>></kbd>. For that, I tried to use this code (example): *(To learn about "XXX" in `:XXX:hotstring::replacement`, please consider [this documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs_1.0/Hotstrings.htm).)*

```
:B0?*:^^|_:: ;Writes ⮤ the first way - B0 + {Backspace 4} for reliable backspacing
Send, {Backspace 4} ;{U+2BA4}, See below ↩  ;⮤
:?*:^|_:: ;Writes ⮤ the second way
Send, {U+2BA4} ;⮤
return
```

The presented script replaces <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> <kbd>̲</kbd>  with `⮤`, which works as intended, the "first way" is for convenience.

As <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd> is typically used to produce only `^` (see below), I would like to have the four keys <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> <kbd>̲</kbd>  also produce `⮤`. Which it does, triggering the "second way" too - but it adds an additional backspace (Means it sends <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>`⮤` in the end). (How) is that possible? Can you detect weather the "leave lock in state"-<kbd>SPACE</kbd> was typed or not? Because it's not actually printed.

The problem I see is that <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> <kbd>̲</kbd>  counts four, but types only three chars (`^|_`).

---

***Footnote:***

How the "lock in" behavior of [diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) works: In order to produce for example `^^`, you could type just <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> but also this: <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd> (which does not produce `^ ^` ). Just typing one accent (<kbd>^</kbd>) leaves the keyboard waiting for something to accent on (typîcàlly á vóvêl) without producing a typed character so far (→ [dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key)). If you then enter <kbd>SPACE</kbd> afterwards, the "lock in" or wait mode is quit without producing the typed space. Typing anything else including another accent prints both chars for the second one typed - on a german keyboard, this is true for all three accent keys.

**More details of this behavior and layout**: The german keyboard contains `^` (plus `°`) and `´`/`` ` ``, which are called the accent keys. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>´</kbd> and then <kbd>a</kbd> produces the letter <kbd>à</kbd> for example. This "locked in" behavior of the accent keys (also described above) is presumably also true for other layouts possibly including french/belgian/suisse/spanish/turkish/etc.

The German keyboard looks like that:
[image: From http://eddieindeutschland.blogspot.com/2011/05/german-keyboards.html]